# Progress bar closes too soon with ggplot

Tags: r, shiny, tidyverse

I wonder if someone can explain the behavior of the progressBar().
I have trimmed my shiny app to the bare minimum to reproduce this post.

Now to the problem. When I select "AllRuns", the progress bar pops up and then goes away
before the graphic is displayed. But when I select "scatter", the progress bar nicely waits
until the scatter plot is displayed on the main panel. Is this a normal behavior?
How can I make the progress bar wait until the graphic displays when "AllRuns" is selected?

**UPDATE** The dataset can be read into R from google docs. it takes about 20 seconds to load into R.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)
library(data.table)

final <- fread("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/170235QwbmgQvr0GWmT-8yBsC7Vk6p_dmvYxrZNfsKqk/pub?output=csv")

runs<- c("AllRuns","scatter")

ui <- fluidPage(
             sidebarLayout(
               sidebarPanel(
                  selectInput(inputId = "run",
                  label = "Chinook Runs",
                  choices = runs,
                  selected = "AllRuns"),
      
      sliderInput(inputId = "Yearslider",
                  label="Years to plot",
                  sep="",
                  min=2000,
                  max=2014,
                  value=c(2010,2012))),
      mainPanel(
        plotOutput("plot")
       )))

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  session$onSessionEnded(function() {
    stopApp()
  }) 
  
  plot_all <- reactive({
    final[final$year >= input$Yearslider[1] & final$year <= input$Yearslider[2], ] 
    })
  
  plotscatter <- reactive({
    rnorm(100000)    
  })
  
  dataInput <- reactive({
    if (input$run == "AllRuns") {
      plot_all() 
    }else{
      plotscatter()
    }
    })
 
  # Plot data
  create_plots <- reactive({
    withProgress(message="Creating graphic....",value = 0, {
      n <- 10
      for (i in 1:n) {
        incProgress(1/n, detail = input$run)
        Sys.sleep(0.1) 
      }    
      
    #Make the plots
      theme_set(theme_classic())
      switch(input$run,
             "AllRuns" = ggplot(plot_all(),aes(SampleDate,Count,color = race2)) + 
               geom_point() + theme_bw() +
               labs(x="",y="Number in thousands",title="All Salmon Runs combined"),
             "scatter" = plot(plotscatter(),col="lightblue")
            )
      })#Progress bar closing brackets
    })#create_plots closing brackets 
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    create_plots()
  }) 
  
}
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simple that the progress bar is updated by the for-loop and the plot code only run after the for-loop. So the progress-bar reach the end, then plot code started. This kind of progress-bar would work if you are process something along with for-loop for example

```
list_of_files # assume you have a list of data file to read and process
max_progress <- length(list_of_files)
withProgress(message="Creating graphic....",value = 0, {

      for (i in 1:max_progress) {
        data <- read_csv(list_of_files[i])
        ... # doing something here
        # once the processing code done next line of code will update the progress bar
        incProgress(1/n, detail = input$run) 
      } 
})
```

If you want to display loading one way to do it is using `shinycssloaders::withSpinner()` on the UI part which would show an animation of loading while UI is updating by server side.

The `withProgress` would be more useful when you have a list of items to process.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)
library(data.table)
library(shinycssloaders)
final <- fread("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/170235QwbmgQvr0GWmT-8yBsC7Vk6p_dmvYxrZNfsKqk/pub?output=csv")

runs<- c("AllRuns","scatter")

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(inputId = "run",
                  label = "Chinook Runs",
                  choices = runs,
                  selected = "AllRuns"),
      
      sliderInput(inputId = "Yearslider",
                  label="Years to plot",
                  sep="",
                  min=2000,
                  max=2014,
                  value=c(2010,2012))),
    mainPanel(
      withSpinner(plotOutput("plot"))
    )))

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  session$onSessionEnded(function() {
    stopApp()
  }) 
  
  plot_all <- reactive({
    final[final$year >= input$Yearslider[1] & final$year <= input$Yearslider[2], ] 
  })
  
  plotscatter <- reactive({
    rnorm(100000)    
  })
  
  dataInput <- reactive({
    if (input$run == "AllRuns") {
      plot_all() 
    }else{
      plotscatter()
    }
  })
  
  # Plot data
  create_plots <- reactive({
    #Make the plots
    theme_set(theme_classic())
    switch(input$run,
           "AllRuns" = ggplot(plot_all(),aes(SampleDate,Count,color = race2)) + 
             geom_point() + theme_bw() +
             labs(x="",y="Number in thousands",title="All Salmon Runs combined"),
           "scatter" = plot(plotscatter(),col="lightblue")
    )
  })#create_plots closing brackets 
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    create_plots()
  }) 
  
}
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mind showing a quick toy graphic implementing `shinycssloaders::withSpinner()` as I have not idea how is done?

Comment: Just updated the answer using your code 95% just remove `withProgress` and added `withSpinner(plotOutput("plot"))` in UI code.